How to solve the cargo build-sbf error?
I have just started with rust and solana.
Firstly, I created a solana program using the command:
cargo init hello_world --lib

everything ran fine, and then i read from the official docs, to build i ran the command:
cargo build-sbf

this command is not running at all.
The errors i got:
platform tools 404 not found (solved)
now after some days, i tried again:
deleted the initial project and created "hello_world" again using the same command.
by default the cargo.lock is creating a version = 4 and someone suggested to change it to 3, i did.
The error i am stucked at now is:
MacBook-Air hello_world % cargo build-sbf
error: package `solana-program v1.18.26` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.26 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `solana-program` supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev

The versions on my system right now is:
MacBook-Air hello_world % rustc --version; solana --version; cargo --version;
rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)
solana-cli 1.16.10 (src:382b3f16; feat:3712769919, client:SolanaLabs)
cargo 1.75.0 (1d8b05cdd 2023-11-20)

i did everything i knew, and i am not able to just build my program.
Also, using rustup show, the output is:
MacBook-Air hello_world % rustup show
Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/sani/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin
1.75.0-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
solana

active toolchain
----------------

1.75.0-x86_64-apple-darwin (directory override for '/Users/sani/Desktop/projects/hello_world')
rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)

Any help on what I can do?
PS: I know i can use solana playground but i want to setup the local environment for learning.

You are using an old version of the solana tool suite while the crates being pulled into your project are new versions of solana-program
Update your tool suite and try running the program again
solana-install update

Please note that if you get to versions > 1.18 this command has been changed to agave-install

Initially, I used the agave.xyz to install the stable version of cli. And, was getting the same error. I read on the internet that latest solana 2.x is not yet stable with anchor 0.30, so downgraded it. Still I'll upgrade and give it a try.

In that case, the recommend version is 1.18.17 which can be updated to using solana-install init 1.18.17. release notes
